# Match string of numbers in different capture groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have regular expression, `"((?:\d*\.)?\d+)"`, and I want to get all numbers in different capture groups.

Something like this:

```
String sInput  = "20004 8 19 0 1 25. 1. 0. 0. 8 8 6366. 305.4 305.4 15915 8 4 25. 0."
String sRegExDef="((?:\d*\.)?\d+)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sInput, sRegExDef, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

matches[0].Value="20004";
matches[1].Value="8";
matches[2].Value="19";
.
.
.
matches[n].Value="...";
```

What I am looking for is a way to get the numbers in different capture groups.

Comment: do you want the numbers after the dot?

Comment: What is your result? Because on [Regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=17e87064-d4e5-4e9a-8695-bdc0d243ae20), your regex seems to work.

Comment: I do not know how reliable  Regexhero is but my C# project gets only one match (with the same configuratin).

Comment: In Regexhero the Matches got all the same Group name what in my opinion means there are in the same Matching Group and thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
string[] matches = Regex.Split(sInput, @"[^\d.]+");
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wd2GXQ)

- Updated with [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) solution.

Comment: You must exclude the dot from your character class: `[^\d.]+`

Comment: You only have 1 match!

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the split method is not an option for my current problem. 
Not all strings that I have to read in are number based.

Comment: i´m going to do a work around (if(match) => Split =>if(mach ok) => do something) because i haven't find a solution so far. But if there are some other ideas i would be glad to hear them^^ thanks to all^^

Answer (score 0):

if you want every number (numbers after dots included as new numbers)

```
 String sRegExDef=@"((?:\d*)?\d+)";
```

Comment: Why not, but in this case, you can simplify the pattern to: `\d+`

Comment: It is possible to get the numbers after the whitespace?